# how to write the python "with" statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement, file-read

I have this code, which I'm supposed to write using the 'with' statement or 'with' method. If any of you have an idea of how to do it, or any initial idea for me to take I'd be grateful.

```
def read_csv(folder_file, sep):
    '''
    reads a csv file,
    folder_file: a string containing file location and file name
    sep: string containing the separater of records in each line
    '''
    mFile = open('earthquake_Curico_2010-02-27_acclerations_in_cms-2_time_in_s.csv', 'r')
    csvData = []
    for line in mFile:
        csvData.append(line.replace('\n','').split(sep))
    mFile.close()
    return csvData
```

`earthquake_Curico_2010-02-27_acclerations_in_cms-2_time_in_s.csv` is a file I have on my laptop, it's not necessary for you to have it (I think).

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
def read_csv(folder_file, sep):
    '''
    reads a csv file,
    folder_file: a string containing file location and file name
    sep: string containing the separater of records in each line
    '''
    with open('earthquake_Curico_2010-02-27_acclerations_in_cms-2_time_in_s.csv', 'r') as mFile:
        csvData = []
        for line in mFile:
            csvData.append(line.replace('\n','').split(sep))

    return csvData
```

Answer (score 3):

You might try something like this:

```
def read_csv(folder_file, sep):
    '''
    reads a csv file,
    folder_file: a string containing file location and file name
    sep: string containing the separater of records in each line
    '''
    csvData = []
    with open(folder_file) as mFile:
        csvData = [l.strip().split(sep) for l in mFile]
    return csvData
```

1. Using `with` doesn't require you to open/close file and catch exceptions.
2. If you use `open()` for read-only operations, you can get rid of `r` since it's by default.
3. `line.strip()` is more straightforward than `line.replace('\n','')`.
4. Put `csvData` out of `with` to make sure `csvData` is always defined even when the file doesn't exist.